# MySQL -- method for updating table

Tags: mysql

Apologies for the unsophisticated terms and methodological crudeness in advance.

Let's say I have a couple tables like so:

```
ARTISTS
artistId | artistName
       1 | Led Zeppelin
       2 | Pink Floyd


ALBUMS
cdId | artistId | title
   1 |        1 | Physical Graffiti
   2 |        1 | Led Zeppelin IV
   3 |        2 | Wish U Were Here
```

I'm trying to figure out a flexible way to update the ALBUMS table under a couple situations (though in the actual tables I have, title is actually title_id keyed to the ids stored in a separate table).

i. If I sell my two LZ CDs and buy "Houses of the Holy," should I just delete all existing records in ALBUMS where `artistId = 1` and insert the new one as a way of "updating"? My concern here is the possibility of running out of AUTO_INCREMENT primary key ids, though I admit that I doubt that what I have in mind is going to see so much traffic that an unsigned INT can't handle, and a lot easier to implement than my current convoluted idea (for `n` new records I want to add, look for the first `n` out of `m` existing records that don't match, update those records, and remove the remaining `m - n` now extraneous records, which at the least requires a preliminary subquery to get the AID if I'm basing the update on "Led Zeppelin").

i.1. What if I want to add "HOTH" but remove "IV"? Should I still delete both existing records and add them both anew?

ii. What if I just want to correct a typo, as in `cdId = 2`?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this [article](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/03/primary-keys-ids-versus-guids.html) makes you change your mind and use GUIDs instead auto_increment for your primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

I.  Personally, I never delete rows if I can help it.  Consider adding a quantity field to store how many instances of said album are in stock.

You are highly unlikely to run out of auto-increments, but if you're in doubt... use a bigint.  You will never sell that many albums.

I.1  Again, deleting rows like that is bad practice.  If you have a quantity field, increment one, decrement the other.

II.  Correct a typo?  As in "UPDATE `ALBUMS` SET title='Led Zeppelin ZOSO' WHERE cdId=2"?

Answer (score 0):

I would keep ALBUMS as a list of all albums that each artist made, and made table OWNAGE where there would be cdId's of albums you own(or id of user and cdId, or id of user, cdId and quantity)